# Convert MYSQL time to EST

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

Given this result from a mysql database

```
2015-01-20T23:27:42.000Z
```

How would i go about changing this to EST format? Specifically, I need to turn it into this format:

```
October 31, 2013 12:36 PM EST
```

So far I've tried changing it to a utc string like this:

```
var str = new Date('2015-01-20T23:27:42.000Z');
str.replace('GMT', 'EST');
var out = new Date(str);
```

This seems to do nothing and gives me back the original time. Help?

Answer (score 0):

You want a Javascript Date object, and then a library for formatting (since that's not built in). If you do

```
var date = new Date('2015-01-20T23:27:42.000Z');
```

you have a date object. Then, I would look for a library for formatting. A quick Googling turns up http://momentjs.com/ which looks promising.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the moment.js parse library, otherwise i'd be done.